# What did Aragorn's crown look like?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Was there ever a visual representation of the crown Aragorn wore upon becoming king? I know they had one for the movies, but I'm wondering whether Tolkien ever drew one himself. Is there a detailed description of it I can find?

Comment: In the Extended Edition making-of featurettes for *Return of the King*, they talk a little bit about how they designed the crown for the film.  I don't remember the specifics, but I don't think they mentioned any drawings or detailed descriptions from Tolkien.  If I recall, the main influences were the wings from the Gondorian helmets and the white tree, neither of which are unique to the crown itself.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Do you remember which featurette?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The following image was hand-drawn by Tolkien and attached to his [letter #211](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_211) to super-fan Rhona Beare.

[image]

The letter also had the following description:

> *I think the crown of Gondor (the S. Kingdom) was very tall, like that
>   of Egypt, but with wings attached, not set straight back but at an
>   angle.* - <sub><sup>[The Letters of J. R. R. Tolkien - Letter #211](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Letters-J-R-Tolkien/dp/0261102656)</sup></sub>

which, in turn nicely matches the overall description from LOTR

> It was shaped like the helms of the Guards of the Citadel, save that
>   it was loftier, and it was all white, and the wings at either side
>   were wrought of pearl and silver in the likeness of the wings of a
>   sea-bird, for it was the emblem of kings who came over the Sea; and
>   seven gems of adamant were set in the circlet, and upon its summit was
>   set a single jewel the light of which went up like a flame. <sub><sup>LOTR - The Return of the King</sup></sub>

Comment: Dammit, Richard, stop knowing so many things.

Comment: @Nerrolken - [Well excuuuuuuuse me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjv7k54YTa0&feature=youtu.be&t=1m30s)

Comment: *SNORT*. I mean, ahem. Ok, now this crown and the Balrog are two things I believe Peter Jackson did better than Tolkien. Before it was just the Balrog.

Comment: @Richard - You can keep knowing things, but please stop being so quick to answer questions that I know the answer to.

Comment: I can add that the shape of the crown was based on the plain helms worn by the Men of Nùmenor in battle.  Anárion wore one such helm as his own crown, but it was crushed by the catapult-launched rock which killed him.  Another, similar helm, that worn by Isildur in the same battle in which Anárion fell, replaced the first one.  During the reign of Atanatar II, the crown of Isildur was replaced by a new one, similar in shape, but far more elaborately decorated with jewels and precious metals.  This last crown is the one Aragorn received at his coronation as the King of Gondor and Arnor.

Comment: @Omegacron - Two points- 1.  I would add the physical appearance of the Nazgûl to your list of things Jackson improved upon.  2.  In everything I have read, Tolkien leaves the appearance of the Balrogs up to the reader's imagination.  Do you know of some kind of illustration of a Balrog drawn by Tolkien himself?  I haven't heard of anything like that, but I would love to see it, if it exists.

Comment: @WadCheber Sounds like another question. ;)

Comment: @Omegacron The concept of Balrog changed a lot during time, from a creature twice as big as a man and not so scary to a Maiar. Jackson probably represented this late version and considering Maiar could change shape it may even be "accurate". Though Tolkien says it was more shadow than flames on the bridge...

Comment: Oy. Putting wings on a dunce cap doesn't make it any less a dunce cap. :/

Comment: @Martha - Don't let Aragorn hear you say that...

Comment: Thanks to those little lines, I'm now imagining the jewel at the top blinking on and off like an aircraft warning light.

Comment: @Leushenko According to the text description ("*...and upon its summit was set a single jewel the light of which went up like a flame*"), I think you might not be far off...

Comment: Omegacron & Martha - no, Tolkien did the crown better than Peter Jackson.  The crown of Aragon in the movies is a dinky thing that gives no idea of what rank the wearer has or even if it has no connection to rank, like some male tiara.  https://www.google.com/search?q=crown+of+aragorn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj727Ks6KXUAhWI6iYKHbgNAycQ_AUICigB&biw=1280&bih=845  The crown of Gondor is inspired by the white crown of Egypt but made out of silver and mithril and studded with giant diamonds and having wings attached.

Comment: Martha - this is what dunce caps look like. https://www.google.com/search?q=Dunce+cap&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJoJrs6aXUAhVF7iYKHeldDCwQsAQIQA&biw=1280&bih=845    This is what the white crown of Upper Egypt looks like.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Dunce+cap&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJoJrs6aXUAhVF7iYKHeldDCwQsAQIQA&biw=1280&bih=845#tbm=isch&q=cron+of+egypt

Answer (score 15):

I can only hope to supplement Richard's excellent answer, not supplant it.

The first [Crown of Gondor](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Crown_of_Gondor) was a simple, unadorned war helm, of the sort worn in battle by the Men of Nùmenor.  The first of these was destroyed when the King of Gondor, Anárion, was crushed by a rock launched from a catapult or similar device.  Then, the helm of Isildur, which was presumably almost identical to the first, was used as the Crown of Gondor.

These helms were quite plain in appearance, with few decorations or embellishments (or perhaps none at all).  Later, a new Crown was created for King Atanatar II; it was similar in shape to the previous crowns, but was elaborately decorated with jewels and precious metals.

When the royal line was broken, and the throne sat empty for many centuries, the Crown of Gondor rested upon the tomb of King Eärnil II inside the Houses of the Dead above Minas Tirith.  When Aragorn made his claim to the throne, this third crown was used in his coronation as King Elessar Telcontar.  After his death, the crown passed into the hands of his son, Eldarion.

The King wore the crown only during official ceremonies and when performing certain functions in his role as king.  On less formal occasions, he would wear a simple band of mithril, called a filet, in which was set a beautiful jewel known as the Elendilmir, or [Star of Elendil](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Star_of_Elendil).

A Tolkien Gateway user named Grond produced this image of the crown, based on Tolkien's own illustration:

[image]